# Counting occurrences inside nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project I have a nested dictionary that looks like:

```
{1: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Red'},
     {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Blue'}],
 2: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'},
     {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Green'}],
 3: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'},
     {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Blue'}]}
```

where 1-3 represent person 1-3.

The goal is to count reoccurring traits that the persons share.
In above example; `trait_type` `'Background'` counts 2x 'Blue', and 1x 'Red',
and `trait_type` `'Eyes'` counts 2x 'Blue', and 1x 'Green'.

In reality, this dictionary is much larger. How can I efficiently count these traits using python?

Comment: You'll have to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, will do so next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

```
t = {1: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Red'},
         {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Blue'}],
     2: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'}, 
         {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Green'}],
     3: [{'trait_type': 'Background', 'value': 'Blue'}, 
         {'trait_type': 'Eyes', 'value': 'Blue'}]
    }

traits = [(s['trait_type'], s['value']) for r in t.values() for s in r]
[print(f'trait type: {trait[0]}, value: {trait[1]}, count: {traits.count(trait)}') for trait in sorted(set(traits))]
```

Which prints:

```
trait type: Background, value: Blue, count: 2
trait type: Background, value: Red, count: 1
trait type: Eyes, value: Blue, count: 2
trait type: Eyes, value: Green, count: 1
```

Comment: thank you, this is perfect for my purposes! Is there also a way to access the index information? For example show traits per person:
`1: trait type: Background, value: Red, count: 1
trait type: Eyes, value: Blue, count: 2`

Comment: @KL0297 - for the followup you'd need to ask a new question. generally this site's not quite as rude as demonstrated on this question, but, as pointed out above, showing some code on what you've tried so far is best - otherwise it's just asking someone else to do your homework.

Comment: thanks @keithpjolley, your solution was really helpful and it's very much appreciated. Next time I'll add my initial code to the question.